# How to do pagination with a mongodb aggregate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

While working on MongoDB.I have a problem with doing Pagination.When  I'm trying to include Paginaiton with aggerate.I'm also trying to include `facets` in this.

My code: Just for doing search

```
app.get("/search", async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const text = req.query.text

      let result = await collection.aggregate([                    
            {
                '$search': {
                    'text': {
                        'query': `${text}`,
                        'path': 'title'
                    }
                }
            }
        ]).toArray();
        res.send(result)
    } catch (error) {
       console.error(error)
    }
})
```

**This works** for both `search` as well as `pagination`.
like this, see, It doesn't require any optional `request.query.page`.

```
http://localhost:4000/search?text=mango
http://localhost:4000/search?text=mango?page=1
```

---

---

Now, I want to include the `pagination` with **facets search** as well...So,

```
server.get("/search", async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const key = req.query.key;
        const value = req.query.value; 
        const text = req.query.text;
        const page = req.query.page; //Page query create

    let result = await collection.aggregate([                    
            {
                '$search': {
                    'text': {
                        'query': `${text}`,
                        'path': 'title'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                '$match': {
                    [key]: `${value}`
                }
            }
        ]).toArray();
        res.send(result)

    } catch (error) {
       console.error(error)
    }
})
```

**work for this**: **without no.of Pages**

```
http://localhost:4000/search?text=Mango&key=Brand&value=rasna
```

**Doesn't work for Pagination**:

```
http://localhost:4000/search?text=Mango&key=Brand&value=rasna&page=2
```

where I'm wrong here? Do I need to create any additional `function` to make this works or Something else?

Comment: I don't see you using the `page` value anywhere...? Shouldn't you be doing something like https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/#pagination-example?

Comment: @Tomalak Help me with this man pls..   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68431280/express-js-unlimited-query-parameter

Answer (score 1):

you can use both $skip and $limit aggregation pipelines to achieve this purpose. imagine that we want to have only 20 items per page. so our code looks like this:

```
    server.get("/search", async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const key = req.query.key;
        const value = req.query.value; 
        const text = req.query.text;
        const page = req.query.page - 1; //We subtract one because we don't want skip first twenty items in first page

    let result = await collection.aggregate([                    
            {
                '$search': {
                    'text': {
                        'query': `${text}`,
                        'path': 'title'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                '$match': {
                    [key]: `${value}`
                }
            },
            { $skip: page * 20 },
            { $limit: 20 }
        ]).toArray();
        res.send(result)

    } catch (error) {
       console.error(error)
    }
})
```

Comment: @Tomalak I do this when i declare "page" variable in line 6.

Comment: Didn't see that, sorry!

Comment: @parastootaleiniya  Please solve this problem :) 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68431280/express-js-unlimited-query-parameter

Comment: @DivyanshuSah I did it. I hope it is not too late.

Comment: @parastootaleiniya. thank you sooooooo much.